# Two if statements in a for loop?

Tags: arrays, python-3.x, if-statement

```
class Solution:
    def transformArray(self, arr: List[int]) -> List[int]:
        x=arr
        while True:
            f=True
            for i in range(1,len(arr)-1):
                if arr[i-1]<arr[i] and arr[i]>arr[i+1]:
                    f=False
                    x[i]=x[i]-1
                    print(x[i])
                if arr[i-1]>arr[i] and arr[i]<arr[i+1]:
                    f=False
                    x[i]=x[i]+1
                    print(x[i])
                
            #print(x)
            x=arr
            if f==True:
                break
        return x
```

In the above code both the if statements don't execute , only the second one does. I have tried using elif but it still doesn't work. What am i missing here?

Answer (score 0):

For your code, I considered two types of examples as input for the array list

**For example 1**, when the arr = [1, 2, 1, 4], the 2nd element is bigger than 1st and 3rd

The first if statement (if arr[i-1]<arr[i] and arr[i]>arr[i+1]:) is working, because both the conditions are met and it gives the output x = [1, 1, 1, 4]

**In example 2**, when the arr = [3, 2, 3, 4], the 2nd element is smaller than the 1st and 3rd

The second if statement (if arr[i-1]>arr[i] and arr[i]<arr[i+1]:) is working, because both the conditions are met and it gives the output x = [3, 3, 3, 4]

So, the working of if statements largely depends on the elements in the array. Both the if statements' purpose is totally opposite. If one satisfies the condition the other will not.

Hope my answer provides some clarification.

Comment: that was indeed the purpose of my code, here is the question i was trying to solve for reference [Question](https://leetcode.com/problems/array-transformation/) , the control always go into one if statement and not in the other one and i am trying to figure out why. It could be something dumb on my part but i can't figure it out.